# /public/rails folder missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, properties

In new rails installation the rails application doesn't contain the /public/rails/ folder and you can't see application properties from the default index.html page

Comment: you need to re-tag this question (with 'rails', 'ruby', or what have you) -- 'properties' applies to just about anything -- too vague.

Comment: welcome to SO. please read the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Which version of rails are you using? I never saw a public/rails folder but this may have existed in older versions. Which kind of properties do you want to see?

Comment: As far as I know the default page is just under `/public/index.html`

Comment: I am having the same problem, Here is my question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164479/deployed-rails-site-on-ec2-using-capistrano-but-it-doesnt-show-up-on-the-brows

Answer (score 0):

You found this in /public/index.html