# Deployed rails site on ec2 using capistrano, but it doesn't show up on the browser,  here is the site  ->   http://passionate4.net/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am using apache passenger to deploy rails application.

I have followed each and every step clearly and everything works fine.
No error message in deployment.

But the site doesn't show up on browser.

Here are the files

```
$ sudo cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/capi_app 

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.passionate4.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/capi_app/public
  RailsEnv production

  <Directory /var/www/apps/capi_app/public>
    Allow from all           
    Options -MultiViews          
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

I also tried to change

$ sudo cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/capi_app

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.passionate4.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/capi_app/current/public
  RailsEnv production

  <Directory /var/www/apps/capi_app/current/public>
    Allow from all      
    Options -MultiViews    
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

--> With this, when i restart apache, I don't get error  (/  / / public) doesn't exist, but site still doesn't show up.

@Martin

$ sudo cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/capi_app

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.passionate4.net
  DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/capi_app/current/public
  RailsEnv production      

  <Directory /var/www/apps/capi_app/current/public>
    Allow from all       
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

-----------  deploy.rb file -------------

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'

#using  RVM!
$:.unshift("#{ENV["HOME"]}/.rvm/lib")
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_type, :user


set :application, "capi_app"
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/#{application}"

role :web, "50.18.155.154"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "50.18.155.154"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "50.18.155.154", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run


default_run_options[:pty] =  true
set :repository,  "git@github.com:jaipratik/capi_app.git"
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "master"


set :user, "ubuntu"            #if error use whats shown in podcast
set :use_sudo, false
set :admin_runner, "ubuntu"

set :rails_env, 'production'     #<<<<<<<<<<    NEW
#set :use_sudo, false   #if error delete this



# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

---

**ubuntu@ip-10-166-185-18:~$ ls -l /var/www/apps/capi_app**

total 8

lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu   46 2011-11-17 19:04 current -> /var/www/

apps/capi_app/releases/20111117190420

drwx-w---- 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 2011-11-17 19:04 releases

drwx-w---- 6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 2011-11-17 09:48 shared

ubuntu@ip-10-166-185-18:~$

---

Comment: Is apache running on the server, and did you add your vhost to the enabled sites?

Comment: Is the passenger Apache module installed/loaded?

Comment: I appreciate you guys trying to help me                          @sparrovv: I did restart using this cmd $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

Comment: @Lloyd Yes i did installed apache module & it installed perfectly $ passenger-install-apache2-module. I remember I did see the browser saying It works!

Comment: @Martin Frost: I remember adding ghost here $ sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/capi_app. vhost lines are given on top of this page.   Do i need to do similar $ sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/capi_app ? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that the `capi_app` config file exists in the `sites-enabled` folder as well.

Comment: The sites listed in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` are usually just symlinks to the actual files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, so what you should do is `ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/capi_app /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Comment: I extracted my comments to an actual answer.

Comment: capi_app is there in both /etc/apache2/sites-available/  & in sites-enabled.    When i try to reload apache sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload.        I get this error ->  Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/capi_app/public] does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your vhost lives somewhere in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, and then make sure to add it to apache, either by using the `a2ensite` command, or by manually symlinking `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your_vhost_name_here` to whatever you called the site.

Possible commands to enable the site (use either one):

```
sudo a2ensite your_vhost_name

sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/your_vhost_name /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
```

After you've done this, make sure to reload apache, by running the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: when i run $sudo service apache2 restart. I get this error ->  Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/capi_app/public] does not exist

Comment: Yes, it gives me a 403 Forbidden response.

Comment: Oh, wait, you're deploying with capistrano! Shouldn't your DocumentRoot in the vhost be this instead: `DocumentRoot /var/www/capi_app/current/public ` ? Capistrano creates a small directory structure by default, containing different releases, and symlinking to the current one. That might be the catch.

Comment: yeah, thats what i changed now. hold on!

Comment: I updated $ sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/capi_app. & placed the copy above in question.  When i tried to restart                         $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload                                        
 * Reloading web server config apache2                                       Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/apps/capi_app/public] does not exist
                                                                      [ OK ]

Comment: You're missing something, because that's the same error. So either you're not changing every instance of that path, or you didn't symlink it to the `sites-enabled` folder. Did you copy the file to the enabled sites, or did you symlink it?

Comment: I also tried to change $ sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/capi_app                                                          
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.passionate4.net
      DocumentRoot /var/www/apps/capi_app/current/public
 RailsEnv production      
<Directory /var/www/apps/capi_app/current/public>
         Allow from all           
         Options -MultiViews          
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>

Comment: That looks good, but how does your `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/capi_app` look?

Comment: I uploaded -> $cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/capi_app , above

Comment: Ok, that looks like it should. And did you restart apache after you made those changes? And also, have you verified that whatever user apache is running as has access to the files?

Comment: Indentation isn't the problem, Indentation became bad when i pasted it here.  Yes i tried to restart apache & I every tried to relax the file access  $ ls -l /var/www/apps/capi_app/
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu   46 2011-11-17 10:32 current -> /var/www/apps/capi_app/releases/20111117103252
drwx------ 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 2011-11-17 10:32 releases
drwx------ 6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 2011-11-17 09:48 shared

Comment: I know indentation isn't the problem, but I fixed it anyway, because I had a hard time reading it.

Comment: And what user does apache run?

Comment: and for that matter, what does the apache log say? I'm receiving a 403 error when I try to visit the page, that should be logged somewhere (like `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or something).

Comment: I totally agree that its hard to read the code.  I am new to this platform.  User that apache run is ubuntu.   I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Martin: I did see couple of 'permission denied'. I pasted the error log (screenshot) here http://wp.me/p1TtAS-aB

Comment: Yes, apache seems to be unable to read the `/var/www/.htaccess` file. `/var/www` is probably referenced somewhere in your apache config (it's usually the default document root).

Comment: Martin, Can you please suggest me a possible solution to this error

Comment: I'm not sure. This might help: http://www.josephburford.com/2008/08/permission-denied-htaccess-pcfg_openfile-unable-to-check-htaccess-file/

Comment: Then it doesn't exist, and that's why apache can't read it. I'm not really a ninja when it comes to apache configs, but this probably has something to do with that.

Comment: The error has changed to "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible" Details are here -> http://wp.me/1TtAS

Comment: output from `ls -l /var/www/apps/capi_app/` might help

Comment: I changed the location of the application as /var/www/myapplication /  & run cap deploy, the 403 error is gone. I still need to do some trick with capify . Please have a look http://passionate4.net/

Comment: SOLVEDD :   At last I was able to RUN. Thanks Stackoverflow & Rails community & specially Martin Frost.

Answer (score 1):

I placed the application at this particular location  var/www/myapplication.

This resolved the error "Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible". I will put all the steps I took to resolve this issue.

In addition to this i'll also blog on how to resolve errors involved with first time deployment of rails 3.1 to ec2. here ->
http://recipe4developer.wordpress.com/2011/11/19/correcting-errors-in-first-time-rails-3-1-deployment-to-ec2/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using Heroku? You get EC2 with very easy deployment.

Comment: I guess most of the big websites even Heroku and Engine Yard are internally deployed on amazon web services. I agree that I wasted plenty of my time correcting my errors & I learned a lot out of it. Moreover if others can deploy on ec2 why can't I?

Comment: Many of the big websites use Heroku. :) If you want to learn EC2, do it yourself. If you actually want to get the job done without reinventing the wheel, use Heroku. :)