# How important is choosing a particular community Ubuntu AMI on ec2 to deploy rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2

I tried my best to deploy rails website on ec2, Unfortunately, I got some weird error like "Symbolic link not allowed" More details here ->

[Deployed rails site on ec2 using capistrano, but it doesn't show up on the browser,  here is the site  ->   http://passionate4.net/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164479/deployed-rails-site-on-ec2-using-capistrano-but-it-doesnt-show-up-on-the-brows)

Question: Is there a better way to choose ubuntu ami? Will that make the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configuration issue. Just fix it.
Have you set `Options FollowSymLinks` in your HTTPD config?

Comment: Maaan  Thank you for the insight. I fixed it!. Have a look http://passionate4.net/       What else should i fix?

Comment: i have my site pointing to 500.html. but in development its working fine. insights please.